# A Question about Doctoral Theses in Mathematics

Tags: soft-question

This is most definitely a soft question, which I'm sure may get some negative attention, and perhaps even be voted closed. However, I genuinely would like to generate answers on this matter as it concerns anyone that decides to get a doctorate in mathematics. (Since I believe this is the best forum to do so, here goes...)

**Question**: *Does a doctoral thesis in mathematics have to contain more than an abstract, a proposition and proof of a new and exciting result?*

I strongly believe that brevity is beauty to mathematicians and see no problem with a thesis that contains a lengthy abstract (~350 words) to generate enthusiasm and then jumps right into the heart of a novel and far-reaching result. The proof provided is *extremely condensed* in the spirit of [Zagier](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31113/zagiers-one-sentence-proof-of-fermats-theorem), leaving almost all details that can be found elsewhere to be found elsewhere, in the works cited. If the result has merit, I see no reason why it can't be submitted or published in such a manner. To support my stance, I offer the following condensed theses:

1. David Rector, "An Unstable Adams Spectral Sequence", MIT (1966), 9 pgs.
2. Burt Totaro, "Milnor K-Theory is the simplest part of algebraic K-theory", Berkeley (1989), 12 pgs.
3. Herman Buvik, A New Proof of Torelli's Theorem, NYU (1962), 12 pgs.
4. Eva Kallin "A non-local function algebra" Berkeley (1963), 13 pgs.
5. Edmund Landau "Neuer Beweis der Gleichung $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(k)}{k} = 0$", Berlin University (1899), 14 pgs.
6. Barry Mazur, "On Embeddings of Spheres", Princeton (1959), 26 pgs.
7. John F. Nash "Non-Cooperative Games", Princeton (1950), 27 pgs.
8. Kevin Walker, "An Extension of Casson's Invariant to Rational Homology Spheres", Berkeley (1989). 29 pgs.

Although I'd appreciate to hear from anyone worth giving his two cents, I'm specifically eager to hear from those senior members of the community.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems more on-topic at [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Although Academia.SE is still in beta, I'm happy to post there. Before I do so, I hope to ask the more mathematically minded here first.

Comment: @ZevChonoles well, the answer will depends on the area of academia, since this will probably not be the same for some other area. I don't feel like this is a good fit, however, as (in the OP's own words), it is meant to create discussion.

Comment: I do not think people are reading PhD theses as much as they did in the past (the Internet). Especially, if the thesis is long, there is a good chance that nobody would bother reading it. While writing a thesis is romantic to some, I think spending more than $3$ days on it (two of which goes to writing the Acknowledgement, and the rest of it goes to copying and pasting the already submitted/published papers) is just a waste of time.

Comment: Also, soft questions are alright, but discussions are discouraged.

Comment: Yes, this fits best in a "discussion" forum, and not in a "question and answer" forum.

Comment: To be fair, I _did_ ask a question.

Comment: I have heard that Norbert Wiener's thesis did nothing but observe that ordered pairs can be construed as plain sets, and therefore that set theory is sufficient to define pairs.

Comment: You forgot to quote [your source](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54775/what-is-the-shortest-ph-d-thesis).

Comment: My opinion has always been that the thesis is mean to demonstrate that you deserve a PhD. If you get lucky and quickly discover some clever short proof of something great is this really deserving of a PhD? The 5 page paper demonstrating it might be a great paper where the purpose is to demonstrate the result. I'd say it is questionable whether or not the 5 page paper is deserving of the PhD. I'd personally flesh it out to at least demonstrate that I have an understanding of the tools that went into it if not also background motivation, applications, and future directions.

Comment: *The proof provided is extremely condensed in the spirit of Zagier, leaving almost all details that can be found elsewhere to be found elsewhere, in the works cited.* I consider this kind of presentation extremely discourteous to the reader. There is some excuse for it in a journal paper; there is none in a dissertation, in which one has essentially unlimited space. (This is independent of whether a single major result, presented without any expository background, ought to be sufficient.)

Comment: @user02138: Not having read any of those dissertations, I have no way to judge whether the proofs are excessively terse by my standards. I might give Landau a pass anyway, since his is from a rather different era and different academic culture. It is certainly possible that I’d consider any or all of the other seven discourteous to the reader, however.

Comment: More to the point, is the aim of a thesis to _explain_ a result to a  wide audience, or is it to _prove_ a result in a mathematically rigorous way?

Comment: @user02138: A thesis is a presentation of one or more results. A presentation of results that makes the reader work excessively hard is *ipso facto* an inferior presentation.

Comment: "I would like to generate discussion" is not really the reason for this site. Generating answers is the purpose of this site. This is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Changing the text from "I would like to generate discussion" to "I would like to generate answers" doesn't change the intent of your posting, it just hides it. The original sentence was a symptom of the problem with the "question," not the actual problem with it.

Comment: I would disagree that you are _clearly_ looking for answers to the question. Perhaps you are looking for answers to the question, but I think it _appears_ to several people including myself that you are looking for something else, such as support for your views, help in winning an argument, or validation of your comparison of your thesis with those of Nash and Mazur. Therefore the fact you are looking for answers is not clear.

Comment: I guess my problem with this question is that I simply don't believe that is true.

Answer (score 41):

In the end, the doctoral thesis has to contain enough to be passed by the readers
(and to satisfy any auxiliary rules of the institution to which it is submitted).  While a very slim thesis is unusual, if the results are good and the writing is comprehensible, I don't see that slimness is necessarily bad.

On the other hand, 
there is a tradition of including a certain amount of expository materials in a thesis, and I think this is useful, both for the readers (who may not be as familiar with the area as the student and advisor, but who have to form a judgement on the thesis) and for the student writing it; it is good to practice writing clear expositional and motivational material, since this is similar to the kind of material that is required in introductions to papers, in grant proposals, in colloquium talks, and all the other things one has to write in one's career that will be read or listened to by people who are not as expert in one's area as oneself.

It is also quite likely that you will be sending a copy of the thesis, or at least a provisional version, to your letter writers, and so any expository or motivational material that will enhance their appreciation of the thesis is certainly worth including.

Overall, bear in mind that while a brevity can be a good thing, if it degenerates into opacity, that is bad.

Comment: Good points. I'd also add that a thesis is also a measure of your expertise in the subject matter and research skills (which is essentialy what the doctorate signifies, not a groundbreaking result), and a short thesis may imply a lack thereof.

Answer (score 17):

Eva Kallin is a colleague of mine from Brown, and she always expressed pride in the brevity of her thesis. In all my professional years, I never heard anyone disparage that dissertation. It seems to me that generally, mathematicians envy those people who have produced unusually short theses.

Remember, no mathematician is expected to show encyclopedic knowledge of mathematics, especially in the thesis that’s submitted.

Comment: how large is her thesis?

Comment: @BЈовић 13 pages, according to the question.

Comment: @Ergwun Ok, thanks. There are many names in the question, and I missed her.

Comment: The thirteen pages is the length as published. I am under the impression that the paper she turned in to the Berkeley Math Dept. was of length 1 page (maybe 2). So, as mentioned in some of the other answers and comments, she presumably included a lot of background and further explanation in the paper that was not necessary for the department.

Comment: @Lubin: if you mean published as in the journal version, the PNAS version of her thesis is 3 pages and 3 lines long (not counting footnotes and references). Depending on the formatting requirement at Berkeley in the 60s, it is quite possible that much of the difference (13 - 3) is made up of typography (double spacing, title/abstract page, and so forth).

Comment: @Willie Wong, thanks for the clarification. Since she has always been more a friend in the department to me than any kind of coworker, my knowledge of her thesis has been second-hand.

Answer (score 16):

[Disclaimer: I’m a fairly junior member of the community — in my 3rd year of postdoc-ing.]

Yes, there are certainly plenty of excellent short theses in maths.  **There’s nothing necessarily wrong with a short thesis;** it doesn’t *have* to contain any more than what you say.

However, I’d suggest being quite careful about the issue.  **In a small thesis based tersely around a key result, that result has to bear a lot more weight** than if it were part of a larger thesis along with a bit more general exploration of the area.  If I go to a restaurant and the portions are tiny, then that can be fine, but the food had better be *really* good.  And this isn’t just silly prejudice: a longer thesis really can exhibit aspects of a candidate’s knowledge and capabilities that a single tersely-proved result, even an excellent one, doesn’t attest to.

Finally, **the audience of your thesis is your PhD committee**.  If the *certain faculty member* is on your committee, or close to people who are, then it’s not good to antagonise them.  What will be read by a wider audience is determined by what’s on your webpage, on the arXiv, or in journals.  If you make sure to make your perfect, terse exposition the more readily accessible one in these ways, then perhaps it may be easier to bite your tongue and write the thesis that will be more acceptable to your thesis committee.

Answer (score 10):

In Littlewood's "Mathematician's Miscellany"
(fairly recently reissued as "Littlewood's Miscellany"),
this exact situation is discussed.
He says that, yes, even a two-sentence dissertation
could be acceptable.
He says that Picard's great theorem
(iirc) with a one-sentence proof is an example.

I $love$ this book and highly recommend it
to anyone with any sort of interest in mathematics.

Comment: I think I read that a while ago, and it's the source of something that has stayed with me to this day. Littlewood writes, *Schoolmaster : ' Suppose x is the number of sheep in the problem '. Pupil : c But, Sir, suppose x is not the number 
of sheep '. [I asked Prof. Wittgenstein was this not a 
profound philosophical joke, and he said it was.]* - I always feel like there is more for me to wrap my head around

Comment: Yep - there is so much great stuff in a relatively small book.

Comment: This book will be available soon for Kindle. It is currently available in paperback. Go get it. Now.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not 100% sure that you yourself are the author of the thesis rather than the supervisor or some other interested party, but since you are offering to send it out by email I am probably safe in assuming the former.

In either case, I think you should consider carefully whether this is the best place for you to air a dispute with another faculty member. It seems likely that involved parties could recognize themselves or you and that this could be seen as unprofessional behavior.

In any case, what do you hope to achieve by asking this question? You are clearly hoping that M.SE users judge your own case, of which they know only your side, on its merits, rather than simply start a theoretical discussion about thesis length. Even if many or all of the answers agree with you, will this really get you any further in your dispute? The responses of strangers on the Internet are not universally considered to be valuable. If they are helpful for mathematics or programming questions, that is partly because they involve questions of information and verifiable fact.

You should also be aware that comparing your work to that done by a list of great mathematicians might not help your case either. This is frequently done by cranks. As you know, those theses might have been short because they were great, but they were not great because they were short.

Maybe a better approach would be to find some faculty member whom you know reasonably well and trust and try to get them to see your side of the story, and advise you on how to go forward. If you can't find anyone to take your side, you need to ask yourself is there is a reason for that.

If your result is great it will be recognized as such, regardless of how it is written up. It would be a shame if the matter became a distraction from your hard work, or if it led to the perception that you were arrogant or disrespectful to your senior colleagues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This situation is not a dispute, nor am I identifying any party. My aim is to simply try to answer an important question regarding theses, so that I can better understand what is acceptable.

Comment: You are not identifying anyone but it is quite possible that the situation, and your profile, will be enough for someone to identify you. You say that you are simply trying to answer an important question, but what answer, other than 'It depends on the thesis (and the student, and the setting)' could you possibly hope to get?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not an academic, but I got a PhD in (applied) maths over 25 years ago and I do regard myself as a mathematician (among other things).

I've always thought that the main point of a PhD is to prove that the author can do original research.  That was certainly why I was always interested in hiring people with PhDs when I used to work in the banking industry, because I wanted to hire creative people who could have their own new ideas.  So my view is that in principle, a short PhD which contains original research would be absolutely fine :-).

However, I think the problem with a short PhD is a practical one.  The university that awards the degree needs to be certain that the author is responsible for the original research in their PhD.  The less there is in the thesis, the less there is to discuss and test in the viva, so establishing that the person is the true source of the exciting new result is much harder.